# Jquery toggle between images

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make a FAQ page in HTML,css and jQuery.
I want to rotate my arrow when opening the question, and rotate it back when clicking on another question. I managed to do it with the `<p>` tags but I'm having troubles now with the image. 
Does someone know how to do this?

This is the code I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/jmex1p5g/62/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var $li_p = $('ul[class="questions"] li').children('p');
  var $li_a = $('ul[class="questions"] li').children('a');
  if($li_p.slideToggle().toggleClass('closed')){
    $li_p.hide();
  }
    $('ul[class="questions"] li').click(function() {
       var ullist = $(this).children('p:first');
       ullist.slideToggle().toggleClass('closed');

        var isVisible = ullist.is(".closed");
        var siblings = $(this).siblings('li');
        $.each(siblings, function (i, key) {
          if ($(key).find('a').hasClass('icon_minus')) {         
              var sibling = $(key).children('p:first');
              $(sibling).slideToggle().addClass('closed');
            $(key).find('a').removeClass('icon_minus').addClass('icon_plus');
          }
        });


      var img_icon = $(this).children('a');
      var image = $(this).children('span');

      var realimage = $(image).children('img');
      if (isVisible === true){
            img_icon.removeClass('icon_minus').addClass('icon_plus');
            realimage.removeClass('rotate');
            $(this).siblings('img').removeClass('rotate');
      } else {
            img_icon.removeClass('icon_plus').addClass('icon_minus');
            realimage.addClass('rotate');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. I would just add/remove a class `.active` to the `li` and then handle the rest via CSS. Or just use a plugin like [this one](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Smooth-FAQ-Accordion-with-jQuery-CSS-FAQ-Slider/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmex1p5g/63/

Basically you should remove the `rotate` class from all images before adding it to the one selected. It is a common practice.

Follows the relevant code:

```
$('ul[class="questions"] li').click(function() {
   // ...
   // code
   // ...

  var img_icon = $(this).children('a');
  var image = $(this).children('span');

  var realimage = $(image).children('img');
  if (isVisible === true){
        img_icon.removeClass('icon_minus').addClass('icon_plus');
        $('li.question img').removeClass('rotate');
        realimage.toggleClass('rotate');
  } else {
        img_icon.removeClass('icon_plus').addClass('icon_minus');
        $('li.question img').removeClass('rotate');
        realimage.toggleClass('rotate');
  }
});

  //... 
  //the rest of code
```

Comment: Thanks. I will not forget this in the future.